# word2vec best library

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, word2vec, deeplearning4j

Hey I want to use word2vec algorithm without implementing it (I saw a lot of places that teaches how to implement one).


does anyone can tell me what is the best lib to use?
I saw there is Genesim, and Deeplearning4j. also TensorFlow but I can't find a place where they have the function that I need (only how to implement with this lib).


can someone give some comparison about efficiency? how easy to use? the word2vec algorithm for each lib?
any helpful tip or resources would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SpaCy](https://spacy.io/) comes with pretrained word embeddings that you can use - it's very easy to use, you can find examples on how to download the embedding and use it [here](https://spacy.io/usage/vectors-similarity#basics).

Comment: I up this answer for its ease to use as of today

Answer (score 0):

The implementation in the Python `gensim` library offers a `Word2Vec` model class that is flexible (with options not available elsewhere) & as fast as the original `word2vec.c` code released by the Google researchers who created the algorithm.

You can see its docs at:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html

There's an intro tutorial that can be run as in a 'Jupyter' notebook:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_word2vec.html